# Navigate to link on image click in content search web part SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-search-web-part

Using **Content Search Web Part**, we are displaying images from picture library.When I click on a image it is redirecting to image's display form but what I need is it should redirect it to  specified link, so created a column (using Existing Site Column) for the image links in picture library...How can I redirect to specified link?

In web part I changed property mappings of "Link URL" to "OWS_URL" from "Path", but it is not redirecting on image click....

Also, have tried to create a New Site Column - "Carousel Image Link", Type as "Text", but it's not visible in Property Mappings (Link URL) drop-down in Content Search WebPart (Edit Mode).

Any ideas please respond. TIA

Answer (score 0):

When we have changed a managed property, or when we have changed the mapping of crawled and managed properties, the site must be re-crawled before our changes will be reflected in the search index. Because our changes are made in the search schema, and not to the actual site, the crawler will not automatically re-index the site.

In SharePoint Online, crawling happens automatically based on the defined crawl schedule. To make sure that our changes are crawled and fully re-indexed, we must request a re-indexing of the site. The site content will be re-crawled and re-indexed so that you can start using the managed properties in queries, query rules and display templates.

Meanwhile, you must ensure the managed property is Retrievable as you want to show it in Content Search web part.

For more information about [search schema in SharePoint Online](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-the-search-schema-in-SharePoint-Online-d4fab46d-ba41-4c03-9d4c-32b5b33198b6).

Information about [how to manually request crawling and re-indexing of a site, a library or a list](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manually-request-crawling-and-re-indexing-of-a-site-a-library-or-a-list-9afa977d-39de-4321-b4ca-8c7c7e6d264e).

As we cannot manually start a full crawl for contents in SharePoint online, you can [contact Office 365 technical support for the crawling requirement](http://blogs.technet.com/b/praveenkumar/archive/2013/07/18/how-to-create-service-requests-to-contact-office-365-support.aspx).

Provide as much additional information as possible to describe your issue.